# UIToolbar is cutted on the bottom

Tags: iphone, sdk, uitoolbar

Hy, my UIToolbar which I added via the InterfaceBuilder gets been cut if i push to the view, but in the subview's I added via the IB a Toolbar on the bottom side but it cut's it still halfway.

[image]
Under the icon there is normally a text..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in interface builder in the attributes tab of the inspector select some status bar as is unspecified

Comment: nope, statusbar is specified..
The Problem is that the TopBar cannot be specified.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**
I figured out, for people who has the same problem..
I'm only get my frame from the tabcontroller and change it.
The IB set's the height of the tabcontroller to 480.0 but the iPhone has only 460.0 so I set it to 460.

Comment: this method is not portable for future versions of ios, the "top bar" can can and should be specified as navigation bar.

Comment: If i set the top bar as navigation bar, it switches every time immediately to 'Unspecified'.